# Wordpress Customizr Theme Modern Style - Child Theme and overwriting templates

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I searched for this over an hour and just don't find how to do this. Maybe the [Customizr](http://presscustomizr.com) themes name is not the best choice for easy searching. :)

Anyway, as far as I read [here](https://docs.presscustomizr.com/article/24-why-and-how-to-create-a-child-theme-with-wordpress) I have to create a child theme and should be able to override any file in the theme I would like to by building up the same folder structure the original file has.

According to [templates/parts/loop.php](https://github.com/presscustomizr/customizr/blob/792b5c62b70399be811848b2a9235941eb15c14b/templates/parts/loop.php#L30) the following two template files should be used by the theme:

```
templates/parts/content/post-lists/post_list_alternate.php
templates/parts/content/post-lists/post_list_plain.php
```

So I copied these two files to my child theme keeping the folder structure, inserted a large-sized span to test but nothing changes when viewing the website.

Can anyone give me a hint what I'm missing? Most information I find in the theme documentation relates to classical style.

Thanks in advance
Steffen

Answer (score 0):

I also asked this question in the [Wordpress theme support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/modern-style-child-theme-how-to-overwrite-templates/#post-10100894) and got an answer.

The template files each belong to a post list layout which can be selected in the theme customizer:
Appearance -> Customize -> Main Content -> Post lists: blog, archives, .. > POST LIST DESIGN > Select a layout

Changing this to the appropriate layout uses the files in the child theme as expected.

Details on which file is used by which layout can be found in the [code](https://github.com/presscustomizr/customizr/blob/792b5c62b70399be811848b2a9235941eb15c14b/templates/parts/loop.php#L30) of the theme.